# Unresponsive charCode statements

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I am currently watching a bunch of introductory videos about using the canvas tag in HTML5 to create simple 2d games.

As I was following the video code - precisely - there was an error somewhere along the way. I tried to draw a rectangle in the canvas that would respond to the navigation buttons and move accordingly.

Here is the main game code:

```
function game() {
    update();
    render();
}

function update() {
    //This is the code that I think is causing an error
    if(keys[38]) player.y--;
    if(keys[40]) player.y++;
    if(keys[37]) player.x--;
    if(keys[39]) player.x++;
}

function render() {
    context.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
}

setInterval(function(){
    game();
}, 1000/30);
```

The site runs perfectly fine when I load it, but it doesn't respond to the user clicks. Thanks for any help in advance.

Below is the keys array that adds an indexed value every-time a the navigation keys are pressed:

```
var keys = [];

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    keys[e.keycode] = true;
}, false);

window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
    delete keys[e.keycode]
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're using the `.keycode` property, all lower case, in your event handlers. That property doesn't exist. Instead, try using the `.keyCode` property, with a capital `C`.

Using a nonexistent property returns `undefined`, so that would always execute `keys[undefined] = true` and `keys[undefined] = false`.

Comment: Thanks a million, this problem has been bothering me for ages.

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt respond to mouse interactions because you just assigned key codes. i assume you can control the rectangle with the arrow keys?
which framework are you using?

Comment: I'm not using any framework. I just created an array of key-states that is triggered when each key is pressed, hence making the character move in a direction according to the array index value